# Не работает код запускаю через ububtu

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
name = input("Как вас зовут? ")
print("Привет,", name)
input("Press any key")
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали среду как python и, скорее всего, запускаете скрипт также: `python yourscript.py`. Запустите как `python3 yourscript.py` и все будет работать.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/230893)

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk ответ вполне содержательный. Кроме, версии Питона я проблем в hello world скрипте из вопроса не вижу.